# Android UTF-8 Encoding quotation marks

Tags: java, android, json, encoding, utf-8

In my Android Application, I'm using the utf-8 charset to get JSON-data from a Server. I'm using the following code to encode the data from server:

```
try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content, "utf-8"));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
}
return response;
```

In my application, I can see all special Characters like ä,ü etc., but the " (quotation marks) are not shown. Below Android 5.0, there is space, in Android 5.0, the is a box instead of the character (as you can see in the photo).
How can I show the quotation Marks with Unicode "\u0084" and "\u0093"?

Here is a Screenshot from Android 5.0 (Api 21)
[image: Android 5.0 Screenshot]

And here one from Android 4.3:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us the code where you put the string containing that `"` quotation mark?

Comment: Which code exactly do you mean? On the server, im using the following command to get an utf-8 encoded string to echo it with php: "$title = utf8_encode($string);", so I'm getting the \u0084 and \u0093 codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `\u0093` and `\u0084` are really control characters. They don't necessarily have an actual representation.

Instead, you should use `\u201C` and `\u201D`

See:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/index.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pi/list.htm

Comment: If he's already at it, he should prefer `U+201E` and `U+201C`, because these are the correct German quotation marks. ;-P

Comment: Thanks, I simply replaced it in Java with the replace() method. It's not the best way, but it works :-)

Comment: if you can't change the server, you don't have much other choice